# Laravel insert key - value to database

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, entity-attribute-value

I have a `car_properties` table,

My table like:

```
id , name , value
```

I have a big form to create a car. There are 40 different inputs. Some of them selectboxes, some of them checkboxes.. I am trying to implement Eav model for this.

I want to add this 40 inputs in one method

I have methods like:

```
 public function set_property($key ,$value){
    $set = new CarProperties;
    $set->name = $key;
    $set->value = $value;
    $set->save();
}


public function Createcar(Request $request){
    set_property('gearbox',$request->get('gearbox'));
    set_property('fuel_type',$request->get('fuel_type'));
    ..
    ..
}
```

What is the proper way to do this? Or can use a `foreach` or..? 
Thanks for help.

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like this:

```
public function CreateCar(Request $request)
{
    foreach ($request->all() as $key => $value)
    {
        CarProperties::create([
            'name' => $key,
            'value' => $value
        ]);
    }
}
```